# regular expression to match java class/interface/enum/annotation definition

Tags: java, regex

I created a regular expression bellow to do this. But it also matches comments like `//This class blabla...`

```
\\S*.*\\s*(class|interface|enum|@interface)\\s+.*
```

Would you help me come out a regular expression to match the java class/interface/etc.. definition only?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just change \S*.\s to ^\s* should do the trick. Then you will only match beginning of the line, any number of whitespace and then the keyword. Of course that would not match a line like "/* comment */ class MyClass", but that would be a pretty unusual one anyway.

^\s*(class|interface|enum|@interface)\s+.*

Answer (score 0):

Regex is not powerful enough to reliably do this. You need a parser that actually understands Java.

You should use one of these:

- [ANTRL](http://www.antlr.org/) with a [Java Grammar](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/compiler-grammar/antlrworks/Java.g)
- [javaparser](http://code.google.com/p/javaparser/) (a Java source code parser)
- [javacc](https://javacc.dev.java.net/) (Java compiler compiler, the javaparser above is based on this)